# Dynamic routing in Next.js with SSG but fetch data on a page only client side (still unknown IDs at build time)

Tags: next.js

I use Next.js with SSG, but some data should only be accessed (fetched live) by authorized users. At the root level I provide the language `[lang]`.

For example the `user` page should be ID based. I don't want to add this pages while build time. But of course the user template should be prerendered with SSG. On the client side I want to use `SWR` to fetch the user data on access.

I don't want to use `/en/user/?id=someone`, I want to use `/en/user/someone/`.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
[lang]
 ┣ user
 ┃ ┗ [userID]
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.js
 ┗ index.js
```

This works while in dev but not after build (404 if I want to access userID 2, 3, ...).

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = [
    { params: { lang: "en", userID: "1" } },
    { params: { lang: "de", userID: "1" } },
  ];

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it!

Simple added a rewrite in the `next.config.js`:

```
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/:lang/user/:userID",
      destination: "/:lang/user?userID=:userID",
    },
  ];
},
```

And finally added `/lang/user.js` and got the parameter with:

```
const router = useRouter();
const { userID} = router.query;
```